# Strange SPAM behavior

Tags: spam

I recently began receiving SPAM with malicious zip files attached. They all looked very similar in nature but from different "senders". I have no need to receive Zip files with other/better options ie dropbox, gdrive etc.

So, I simply created a transport rule in Exchange to simply delete these emails WITHOUT a response to the sender.

Within a day or two I began getting them again, but now they are sending with RAR and Excel attachments which I never got before.

How on earth could the spammers possibly know I am deleting the email at the transport?!?!

I am concerned there is something internal on the network exposing this behavior. However, I am very safe with my PC and browsing habits and have ran multiple scans exposing no security issues on my PC.

Does MS Exchange 2010 do anything at the transport that could be exposing the fact I am deleting them at the transport? Otherwise I am confused how the switch to other files happened so quickly. Obviously, I can block the RAR files in the same manner, but don't really want to block XLSX files.

Comment: This question is not necessarily off-topic, but might be better suited for  http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: They don't know. Everybody is getting those. And you need more sophisticated spam filtering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sending back an NDR, "Message Rejected" or similar, there is no way for the sender to know that Transport is trashing the message without delivering.  It could be that they have just advanced their methods around ZIP, which is commonly filtered.

Reference later than Exchange 2010: [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919236(v=exchg.150).aspx)

The inspection of attachment contents is probably more advanced than what was available in EX2010, but common attachment file types to be blocked would be a good first step.